# How to turn off special schema validation of file cluster.yml in PyCharm?

Tags: kubernetes, pycharm, yaml

PyCharm has a built-in editor for YAML files. I can create any file that ends with ".yml" and it will do syntax check on it. Today I wanted to add a file called `cluster.yml` to my repository. PyCharm thought that it is kubernetes config file and marked all of its content as big fatal error. :-)

[image]

Even code completion works on it, showing various kubernetes options:

[image]

In this particular project, the file has nothing to do with kubernetes. It just happens to have that name `cluster.yml`.

I have tried to "override file type" in PyCharm, but it already has "YAML" file type. I want this extra schema check gone, and get back my simple and effective plain YAML editor and syntax check.

But how?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in the context of an Ansible project, and was similarly annoyed. Solution was:
to uncheck `File->Settings->Editor->Inspections->YAML->Validation by JSON Schema`.

Comment: There's no such "path" in the settings of VS Code Jan. 2023.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same so I changed it to a Weak Warning

[image: IntelliJ]